# Is there a way to have multiple %cursor% statements in Geany?

Tags: geany

When creating Geany snippets is there a way to tab between `%cursor%` expressions?

For example, I created a snippet that should require two %cursor% expressions. Is there a way to enter the first cursor and then "tab" to enter the next?

I did a search and found:

```
require=var %cursor% = require('%cursor%');
```

Comment: I just found this after searching for "geany %cursor%" -- [User-definable snippets](http://www.geany.org/manual/0.18.1/index.html#user-definable-snippets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned inside a comment, [a user defined snippet](http://www.geany.org/manual/0.18.1/index.html#user-definable-snippets) can be used for. This might have more than one cursor. Having this, you can jump forward inside a snippet setting the `Move cursor in snippet` keybinding.